# Does While loop ends when the program return value?

Tags: python, while-loop, return

I am a new learner for Python. I have a question about while loop.
I wrote a program below to look for square roots.
When I input anything but integers, the message "is not an integer" shows up and it repeats itself until I input correct data(integers).

My question is, why does it end loop when it return value on line 5, return(int(val))?

Thank you for your attention.

```
def readInt():
    while True:
        val = input('Enter an integer: ')
        try:
            return(int(val))
        except ValueError:
            print(val, "is not an integer")

g = readInt()
print("The square of the number you entered is", g**2)
```

Comment: ... Because `return()` ends a function, and the loop is in the function.

Comment: A `return` statement exits the current function, including any nested constructs within which the `return` appears.

Comment: Because `return` does exactly as it's name suggests: it  exits the function and **returns** to the point where the function was called.

Comment: I am glad to know the comments, thank you for answering!

Answer (score -1):

To answer your original question, 'return' effectively exits the loop and provide the result that follows the 'return' statement, but you have to explicity print it like so:

```
def read_int(num1, num2):
    while True:
        return num1 + num2


print(read_int(12, 15))
```

If you simply put 'read_int(12, 14)' instead of 'print(read_int(12, 15))' in this scenario, you won't print anything but you will exit the loop.

If you allow me, here are some modifications to your original code:

```
def read_int():  # functions must be lowercase (Python convention)
    while True:
        val = input('Enter an integer: ')
        try:
            val = int(val)  # converts the value entered to an integer

            minimum_value = 0  # There is no need to evaluate a negative number as it will be positive anyway
            maximum_value = 1000000  # Also, a number above 1 million would be pretty big

            if minimum_value <= val <= maximum_value:
                result = val ** 2
                print(f'The square of the number you entered is {result}.')
                # This print statement is equivalent to the following:
                # print('The square of the number you entered is {}.'.format(result))
                break  # exits the loop: else you input an integer forever.
            else:
                print(f'Value must be between {minimum_value} and {maximum_value}.')
        except ValueError:  # If input is not an integer, print this message and go back to the beginning of the loop.
            print(val, 'is not an integer.')


# There must be 2 blank lines before and after a function block
read_int()
```

With the final 'print' that you actually have at the end of your code, entering a string of text in the program generates an error. Now it doesn't ;). Hope this is useful in some way. Have a great day!

Comment: Downvoted: This (i) does not answer the actual original question ("why does loop end when  `return` encountered); and (ii) arbitrarily decides function should break on negative numbers which can be legitimately squared; and (iii) arbitrarily decides function cannot work on large numbers.  (Also, "must be 2 blank lines" is simply a stye convention and not a *must* at all)

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I have modified my answer to at least answer the original question and will take care not to deviate from the topic from now on. If that is of any help, I will leave the rest of the post intact just as a way to offer an alternative to the original code.

Comment: >Sébastien Lavoie: thank you so much for adding some info for my original program. it helped me a lot!!

Comment: >donkopotamus: thank you for leaving the comment. your comment helped me to understand more!